# GLUT-like mouse functions in a non-GLUT created window (suggested workarounds?)

Tags: opengl, c++-cli, glut

I'm creating a windows program (shown below) that contains two OpenGL rendering contexts. Usually when I program using OpenGL, I use the GLUT library functions for the creation and callback registration for my drawing contexts.

However as I'm embedding these contexts into Windows Forms (GLUTwould create them each with their own main window complete with windows min,max and X buttons), I've been forced to create the windows without using GLUT, as System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow(s) that have been enabled as OpenGL contexts using wgl functions.

[image: The kind of OGL views I'm working with]

I however, now have a need to use functions like glutMouseFunc and glutPassiveMotionFunc in order to process user input in these views (These are the functions I usually use for dealing with mouse input). But because these windows weren't created using glutCreateWindow I seriously doubt I will be able to use these GLUT functions in association with them. (I experimented with glutCreatSubwindow however this only creates subwindows of another GLUT-created windows)

What I'm currently looking for is a way to process mouse clicks, coordinates & movements on these OpenGL enabled forms / NativeWindow(s). Whether that be using the System namespace another GL or GLUT function that I don't know about or anything else. I'll also include the code parent class that both views inherit their constructor from, so that you can see how they're created.

```
public ref class COpenGL:
        public System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow
        {
        public:
            COpenGL(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ parentForm, GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight)
        {
            CreateParams^ cp = gcnew CreateParams;



            //set it's position on the parent form
            cp->X = 12;
            cp->Y = 27;
            cp->Height = iHeight;
            cp->Width = iWidth;

            //set the height and width for the benefit of the derived classes,
            //so that they can find out their own size using the getHeight & width funcs
            currentWidth = cp->Width;
            currentHeight = cp->Height;

            //Specify the form as the parent
            cp->Parent = parentForm->Handle;

            //create as a child of the specified parent
            //and make OPENGL compliant
            cp->Style = WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_CLIPCHILDREN;

            //create the window
            this->CreateHandle(cp);

            m_hDC = GetDC((HWND)this->Handle.ToPointer());

            if(m_hDC)
            {
                wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC,NULL);
                MySetPixelFormat(m_hDC);
                ReSizeGLScene(iWidth,iHeight);
                InitGL();
            }


        }

        virtual void Render()
        {
            //simple render, just refresh the buffers for now
            glClearColor(1.0f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        void SwapOpenGLBuffers()
        {
            SwapBuffers(m_hDC);
        }

    protected:
        HDC m_hDC;
        HGLRC m_hglrc; 

GLint MySetPixelFormat(HDC hdc)
        {
            PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 
                sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),    // size of this pfd 
                1,                                // version number 
                PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |              // support window 
                PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |              // support OpenGL 
                PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                 // double buffered 
                PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                    // RGBA type 
                24,                               // 24-bit color depth 
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 // color bits ignored 
                0,                                // no alpha buffer 
                0,                                // shift bit ignored 
                0,                                // no accumulation buffer 
                0, 0, 0, 0,                       // accum bits ignored 
                32,                               // 32-bit z-buffer     
                0,                                // no stencil buffer 
                0,                                // no auxiliary buffer 
                PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                   // main layer 
                0,                                // reserved 
                0, 0, 0                           // layer masks ignored 
            }; 

            GLint  iPixelFormat; 

            // get the device context's best, available pixel format match 
            if((iPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd)) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("ChoosePixelFormat Failed");
                return 0;
            }

            // make that match the device context's current pixel format 
            if(SetPixelFormat(hdc, iPixelFormat, &pfd) == FALSE)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("SetPixelFormat Failed");
                return 0;
            }

            if((m_hglrc = wglCreateContext(m_hDC)) == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("wglCreateContext Failed");
                return 0;
            }

            if((wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hglrc)) == NULL)
            {
                MessageBox::Show("wglMakeCurrent Failed");
                return 0;
            }

            return 1;
        }



        bool InitGL(GLvoid)                                     // All setup for opengl goes here
        {

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluOrtho2D(0,currentWidth,0,currentHeight); //these will be set be now so it's safe to use them
                                                        //also makes sure we're drawing from the bottom left
            //glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                          // Enable smooth shading
            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);               // Black background
            //glClearDepth(1.0f);                                   // Depth buffer setup
            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             // The type of depth testing to do
            glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  // Really nice perspective calculations
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);//activate the alpha blending functionality
            glLineWidth(2);         // Width of the drawing line
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            return TRUE;                                        // Initialisation went ok
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First question:

> I'm creating a windows program (shown below) that contains two OpenGL rendering contexts.

Why are you doing this? Creating multiple contexts I mean? It's perfectly possible to use a single OpenGL context with multiple windows of compatible PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR.

But more importantly: Why are you using two separate windows at all? Just use glScissor and glViewport to select a portion of the window for rendering and use that to draw multiple panes. Switch projection and modelview for each pane appropriately. I'd start by moving the code in your `InitGL` function to the drawing code.

Comment: So with your second point you're saying I should have one GL Context the size of the entire main window, and clip it down using glScissor to two (apparently) separate panes. Rather than having two separate manageable entities?
  As at the moment the two different OpenGL views exist as different contexts, so that I can switch between the two of them for things like drawing, using wglMakeCurrent().

Comment: Having never attempted anything like this before, It seemed the logical way to do it. I intend to have 2 different embedded OpenGL views, displaying different things, that I may want to render or call swapBuffers() on at different times. That is why I have used two contexts.